# Sharing in iOS using buttons/images

Tags: ios, image, share

You all know the share-buttons on mobile websites. If not, here is an example : 
**http://m.chip.de/test/Android-Schutz-Apps-20-Virenscanner-im-Vergleich_75618366.html**

Buttons like this look better then Apple's share extension.

My question is: Is there an easy way to implement buttons like this (with working links)?

Comment: in general its not a great idea to change the look of icons that have a uniform look system wide.  If users are used to seeing a certain icon every time they are going to share by email or facebook and then in your app its completely different, thats confusing.

Comment: Hehe, yes, it might be confusing, but I think those buttons are better "eye-catchers" :)
I allready have the share extension implemented, but was thinking about some extra buttons

Comment: If you set a UIButtons background to be equal to those buttons then yes, all you do is set the target and call your share functions. You are constrained into one look and feel but @Dancreek is correct in the fact that people on iOS are used to one design and Android another, and web another. So it's up to you to implement your design how you want it because trying new things isn't always a bad thing but make sure it conforms to the [Apple UI Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/).